# Converting to binary for decision tree algorithm in oracle

Tags: oracle, data-mining, decision-tree

i have a problem while dealing with data mining

I now attached a picture which show the table that i have. In this table there is a subscriber_id column which is unique and i have to use the decision tree algorithm for this project. Decision tree algorithm accepts only binary numbers and i have no idea how to convert these numbers to binary.

http://ehmad11.com/DM1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision trees should work for non-binary attributes, too. If Oracle doesn't support this, use a better tool.

But don't use the subscriber ID column. The ID is unique to your users, and will appear to be perfect for prediction, but useless in reality.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your "binary numbers" requirements are technically in detail, but one solution would be to convert each character in your string to its binary representation:

```
SELECT
       REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(TRANSLATE ('1.233.234.234-12312312' -- example from you screenshot, subscriber_id goes here
                                   , '.-'                     -- non-numeric characters in your data, extend if more possible
                                   , 'AB')                    -- replacement for non-numeric characters in your data, extend if more possible
                  ,'0','0000')
                 ,'1','0001')
                ,'2','0010')
               ,'3','0011')
              ,'4','0100')
             ,'5','0101')
            ,'6','0110')
           ,'7','0111')
          ,'8','1000')
         ,'9','1001')
        ,'A','1010')
       ,'B','1011')  -- extend to C, D, ... if more non-numerics in your data
        AS bin
  FROM dual
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees should accept non binary attributes.

It seems strange that your tool does not support this. I would suggest to find a better tool.